# A problem from Folland: constructing Haar measure from Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, haar-measure

The following is a result from *A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis* by G.B. Folland. It also appears as an exercise in the real analysis text by the same author. The context is Haar measure on a locally compact group $G$.

> **2.21 Proposition.** Suppose the underlying manifold of $G$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$ and left translations are given by affine maps: $xy = A(x)y + b(x)$, where $A(x)$ is a linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $b(x)\in\mathbb{R}^N$. Then $|\det A(x)|^{-1}dx$ is a left Haar measure on $G$, where $dx$ denotes Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^N$. (Similarly for right translations and right Haar measure.)

There are several questions on this site about this result, e.g., [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384575/haar-measure-a-problem-from-folland), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172246/a-haar-measure-via-the-lebesgue-measure-on-bbb-rd). However, I'm asking a different question:

> Why is $|\det A(x)|^{-1}$ (as a function of $x\in G$) measurable/integrable with respect to the Lebesgue measure?

This is not included in the assumption (though in practice it is usually true) and I can't prove this.

Comment: so $A: G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N^2}$?

Comment: @Timkinsella Yes, $A:G\to\operatorname{GL}(\mathbb{R}^N)$.